# rerun a function with the new set of data after removing the row that do not satisfy a particular condition

Tags: r, for-loop, do-while

I have a function which performs many operations to find the mean, variance matrix, T2 sample values and control limits from a set of data say my_data. Now I have to compare the T2 values with the control limits and if any of the T2 values is more than the control limits, I want to remove the whole sample (represented as a row in my main dataset) from my data set and re-perform my operations with the remaining samples (so I obtain a new dataset) until no T2 value is greater than the limits. I need to store the mean and variance matrix so I used `<<-` in my function for these. I used a while loop (suggested in the answer by @r2evans) in my code but since I'm very new in coding, my code does not stop since. Here is all my code below:

```
## Implementation of the T2 C.C and EWMA-R c.c for the "On-line monitoring" article
## Creating a sample set of data for my online article; representing width as x_points and speed as y_points
width1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
width2 <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
width3 <- c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
corr_speed1 <- c(0.33, 0.37, 0.54, 0.52, 0.66, 0.64, 0.45, 0.66, 0.56, 0.33)
corr_speed2 <- c(0.47, 0.62, 0.57, 0.45, 0.53, 0.4, 0.49, 0.43, 0.38, 0.52)
corr_speed3 <- c(0.5, 0.37, 0.39, 0.72, 0.33, 0.54, 0.43, 0.35, 0.55, 0.41)
sample_boat <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

my_data <-  data.frame(sample_boat, width1, width2, width3, corr_speed1, corr_speed2, corr_speed3)

T2_article_chart <- function(m){
  while(nrow(m)>0){
    x_data <- m[2:4]
    y_data <- m[5:7]
    mean_x_data <- mean(apply(x_data, MARGIN=1, mean))
    mean_y_data <- apply(y_data, MARGIN=1, mean)
    autocorr_x <- mean(apply(x_data, MARGIN=1, var)*(length(x_data)-1))
    
    ## Finding estimates as per sample sizes
    diff_x <- x_data-mean_x_data
    mult_yx <- y_data*diff_x
    a1_m <- apply(mult_yx, MARGIN=1, sum)/autocorr_x
    a0_m <- mean_y_data -a1_m*mean_x_data
    resi_m <- y_data-a0_m-a1_m*x_data
    square_resi <- resi_m^2
    app_func_resi <- apply(square_resi, MARGIN=1, sum)
    MSE_m <- app_func_resi/(length(x_data)-2)
    MSE_all <- sum(MSE_m)/length(MSE_m)
    var_a0_m <- MSE_all^2*(1/length(x_data)+mean_x_data^2*(1/autocorr_x))
    var_a1_m <- MSE_all^2*(1/autocorr_x)
    cov_a1_a0_m <- -(MSE_all^2*mean_x_data*(1/autocorr_x))
    cov_a1_a0_m <- mean(cov_a1_a0_m)
    ## For all the samples j=1,2,...,k
    # First we need to define the number of samples we have (represented by the number of MFC in our article)
    k <- length(a0_m)
    a0 <- sum(a0_m)/length(a0_m)
    a1 <- sum(a1_m)/length(a1_m)
    var_a0 <- var_a0_m/length(var_a0_m)
    var_a1 <- var_a1_m/length(var_a1_m)
    ## We should now define the expected value and the var-cov matrix for each
    # sample and find the sample statistic for our Tsquare control chart
    # when expected mean and cov_var matrix are unknown for Phase I
    z_m <- data.frame(a0_m, a1_m)
    expected_value_U <<- c(a0, a1)
    var_cov_matrix <<- matrix(c(var_a0, cov_a1_a0_m, cov_a1_a0_m, var_a1), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
    #T2_m <- (z_m-expected_value_U)%*%solve(var_cov_matrix)%*%t(z_m-expected_value_U)*(k/(k-1))
    subs_id1 <- vector()
    subs_id2 <- vector()
    for(i in 1:nrow(z_m)){
      subs_id1[i] <- z_m$a0_m[i]-expected_value_U[1]
      subs_id2[i] <- z_m$a1_m[i]-expected_value_U[2]
    }
    samp_mean_diffs <- data.frame(subs_id1,subs_id2)
    T2_samples <- vector()
    for(i in 1:nrow(samp_mean_diffs)){
      T2_samples[i] <- as.matrix(samp_mean_diffs[i,])%*%solve(var_cov_matrix)%*%t(as.matrix(samp_mean_diffs[i,]))
    }
    T2_samples <- cbind(T2_samples)
    # Control limits for T2 control chart 
    upper_control_limit_t2 <- 2*qf(0.95,2,(length(x_data)-2)*k)
    for(i in 1:nrow(T2_samples)){
      if(T2_samples[i]>upper_control_limit_t2){
        m <- m[-c(i),]
        repeat{T2_article_chart(m)}
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
T2_article_chart(my_data)
```

Comment: (1) you need a `while` loop that operates at least once, perhaps `REDO=TRUE; while (REDO) { do_something; REDO=(my_condition); }`. (2) I suggest your function should `return` something (so that you can do something with it), vice `print` it which is immediately lost (and is purely in side-effect). (3) Your `for` loop is defined based on the original size of `multi_xx`, though that is a changing length. (4) Use `seq_len(...)` instead of `1:length(...)`, the latter breaks when it is length 0 (you should program defensively).

Comment: Given that random input, I think it would really help if you provide your expected output, as it is not perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Another question ... based on this calculation, why do you need to recalculate `multi_xx`? The math never changes, so all you need to do is remove the problem rows from `multi_xx` *once* and return it. Is your `(x*2)^2` a placeholder for a more complex formula that changes based on the dimensions of `x`?

Comment: Hi r2evans, thanks for your help. For a better understanding, I'm designing a T2 Hotelling control chart from a certain article (phase I). so I want all the T2 samples statistics to be inside a the control limit. If one is out of control, I need to remove it and recalculate the estimates and the T2 sample statistics until everything is in control. When I have everything in control, i need to store the estimate parameters for the next phase II (mean and sigma matrix).

Comment: So that means your `(x*2)^2` is an over-simplification of your actual process, is that right?

Comment: yes. Sorry for the late response. I'm still confused on how this platform works. and what I want to store in my r environment is the multi_xx

Comment: *"store in my r environment"* ... do you mean `multi_xx <- yy(x)` given one of my functions below? While it is possible to assign to `multi_xx` from within the function, that's really bad form and can very easily break things in unexpected (and silent) ways, I discourage this method of programming. Think of a function as having no side-effect, you can run it a million times (on the same input) and nothing in the calling environment changes; from there, realize that you want the function to give you the resulting value, that you can store anywhere (e.g., `multi_xx` in the global env).

Comment: Can I put the whole function I have written in the comments so that you better picture what I want to do?

Comment: No! Edit your question directly. Comments are easily hidden and/or overlooked, it is better to keep your question whole and reproducible.

Comment: Okay. What I mean is that I have a function which performs many operations like calculating the mean, variance matrix, T2 sample values and control limits from a set of data say my_data. Now I want to compare the T2 values with the control limits and if any of the T2 values is more than the control limits, I want to remove the sample from my data set and re-perform my operations with the remaining samples until no T2 value is greater than the limits and now I store the mean and variance matrix in the global environment.

Comment: I used <<- to store the mean and variance matrix and it worked so my problem now is to able to repeat the whole function when I have some violations so as to re-calculate my parameters.

Comment: (1) Don't use `<<-`, it is almost certainly wrong here. (2) I *still* do not know what you are really doing. Lashawn, my answer addresses the issue you have asked, though it is not the problem that you have. You need to update your question with relevant code and expected behavior/output. Otherwise I'm out, I cannot help what I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

If your `(x*2)^2 > 10` really is the filtering function, then recalculating `x` each time is unnecessary: remove the high rows and just return. (Said differently: once you remove the rows of `x` that cause the problem, none of the others will ever produce something different. So don't iterate.)

```r
yy <- function(x, cutoff = 10) {
  ind <- rowSums( (x*2)^2 > cutoff ) > 0
  return(x[!ind,])
}
yy(x)
#           [,1]     [,2]
# [1,] -0.560476  1.22408
# [2,] -0.230177  0.35981
# [3,]  1.558708  0.40077
# [4,]  0.070508  0.11068
# [5,]  0.129288 -0.55584
# [6,]  0.460916  0.49785
# [7,] -0.686853  0.70136
# [8,] -0.445662 -0.47279
```

If, however, that's just a placeholder. This says that your actual function is sensitive to the dimensions of the matrix you send in ... in which case, this might work for you.

```r
yy <- function(x, cutoff = 10) {
  REDO <- TRUE
  while (nrow(x) > 0 && REDO) {
    multi_xx <- (x*2)^2
    ind <- rowSums(multi_xx > cutoff) > 0
    if (any(ind)) {
      x <- x[!ind,]
      REDO <- TRUE
    } else REDO <- FALSE
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Normally when I use `while`, I try to put in a self-limiting agent so that it won't iterate forever. For example, I'll often define `iter <- 100` and then use `while(REDO && iter > 0) { iter <- iter - 1; ...; REDO <- something; }` so that it cannot loop forever. However, the logic of this loop is such that it will only iterate until none of them evidence the `cutoff` condition or all rows have been removed.